# Conditionally using a link in ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an app using ASP.NET MVC. I need to be able to sometimes display a link. Other times, I just need to use text. In an attempt to accomplish this, I've written the following in my view:

```
@{
   var showLink = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item["id"].ToString());
   if (showLink) {
     Html.Raw("<a href=\"#\">");
   }
   Html.Raw(item["name"]);

   if (showLink) {
    Html.Raw("</a>");
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working. The name does not render. However, if I put `@item["name"]` just above the `@{` the name appears just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `Html.Raw(item["name"])` inside a code block (`@{ ... }`) - code blocks are run as normal C#; their result is not rendered to the response like inline Razor. Because of that, the string that is returned by `Html.Raw` is just being discarded.

You want:

```
@{
    var showLink = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item["id"].ToString());
}

@if (showLink)
{
    @Html.Raw("<a href=\"#\">");
} 

@Html.Raw(item["name"]);

@if (showLink)
{
    @Html.Raw("</a>");
}
```